# Hacking into WiFi using OS X!

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, software-rec, password-recovery

Is there a software that would help me to crack WiFi? I'm not doing anything illegal, we have a bet going on within our organization (I read that WiFi can be hacked).

my price is lunch (and i'm hungry) ;)

Answer (score 4):

have a stickybeak at a program called [Kismac](http://kismac-ng.org/)

Works well for WEP encryption, and can support packet injection depending on your wireless chipset.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Aircrack](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) suite [on mac](http://aircrack-ng.darwinports.com/) through [darwinports](http://www.darwinports.com/). (or indeed, as mentioned, backtrack has it installed)

WEP, even without packet injection, is cracked trivially in a matter of minutes to hours on a busy network.

WPA is more difficult. What you have to do is capture a four-way handshake, and then mount an offline attack against the key. If you're lucky, you'll not even need packet injection (just wait till someone connects) A simple PSK system is pretty insecure if the key is simple (for example dictionary words, etc...) but mounts in difficulty with the length and complexity of the key. You can use [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) for some serious dictionary attack on the key. If the key is something like `AFK121AJSU2832` the only way you'll find is is an exhaustive key search. ie: out of luck.

If you're using some sort of authentication scheme besides PSK, I have no idea! :-)

I might be talking through my rear end, though. Have a look at the [Aircrack wiki](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=tutorial) for more from people who actually know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

If you have OS X Lion or Mountain Lion then Kismac will have an error because Apple deprecated half of their CoreWLAN framework. I developed an [OS X GUI for Aircrack-NG](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/46004/wi-fi+crack) to hack Wi-Fi networks, it works well with WEP. It's OS X 10.7+ since Kismac works fine in Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special linux distribution dedicated to WIFI hacking :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BackTrack

It can be found in form of a live CD, so you can run it on you Mac without install anything !

Comment: yeah, I remember that software long time ago, do you know if it works with mac? i.e. existing hardware of my mac?

Comment: So far I can remember it works with apple hardware but you need to record a huge amount of traffic in order to crack the wireless key. There are better wireless chipsets than the ones from apple computer that can use packet injection to generate traffic so it will take less time to collect the data.

Comment: It depends on the encryption used.... for example... WEP can be cracked very quickly.

Comment: Yes but you have to collect packets to do that. And if there are not a lot of traffic on the attacked wifi it will take some time ..

Answer (score 1):

The Airport cards don't support packet injection, so it doesn't work well without a USB wireless dongle.

Comment: This all depends on the key, and the amount of network traffic. I have managed to crack heaps of wep networks within 5 minutes without injection (airport extreme).